# Quebra linha em célula de tabela no formato CSV para ser lido pelo Excel

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel, csv

Tenho o seguinte código que insere um valor em uma célula do excel para exportação

```
context.Response.Write("aa\r\nbb\r\nccc");
```

o /r/n quebra a linha porém escreve na célula abaixo, gostaria de quebrar a linha porém continuando com o texto na mesma célula.
Como devo fazer?

Aqui está o código completo

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
context.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=teste.csv");

context.Response.Write("aa\r\nbb\r\nccc");
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Usa o escape da tecla ALT+Enter

Comment: Em que contexto se encontra o código apresentado? Isso me parece um request sendo processado no servidor... como isso poderia parar numa tabela do excel? Adicione mais detalhes sobre a questão.

Comment: Concordo com o @MiguelAngelo, esse cenario apresentado parece que vc está abrindo um arquivo de texto no excel com um contenttype = "application/excel". Desta forma sugiro vc criar um <table> quebrar o texto dentro da <TD> e exibir como conteudo excel.

Comment: Editei a questão com o contexto

Answer (score 2):

Considerando o novo contexto apresentado, para solucionar o problema deverá colocar aspas duplas `"` indicando o texto que terá linhas múltiplas, ou seja:

```
context.Response.Write("\"aa\rb\rccc\"");
```

Referência: [CSV com celulas de múltiplas linhas (Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516222/how-to-write-data-on-multiple-lines-but-within-the-same-cell-of-csv)

Answer (score 0):

O cenario apresentado parece que vc está gerando o conteudo numa aplicação WEB. Desta forma sugiro vc criar um `<table>` em HTML e quebrar o texto dentro da `<TD>`. e exibir como conteudo excel.
Tente:

```
context.Response.Write("<table>" + 
                            "<tr>" + 
                                 "<td>aa<br/>bb</br>cc</td>" + 
                            "</tr>" + 
                       "</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta **salvar uma tabela do Excel em formato CVS**, com um retorno de linha dentro da célula.

Fiz isso no excel 2007 e o que ele salvou foi um `'\n'`. Além disso, colocou o valor da célula dentro de aspas duplas.

Exemplo no C#, de como representar o valor da célula:

```
var celula = @"""a\nb"""; // conteúdo da célula com quebra de linha
```

Answer (score 0):

Os campos com quebras de linha embutidos devem ser colocados dentro de aspas duplas.

```
context.Response.Write("2013;Chevrolet;Cruze;\"linha1"+ "\r\n"+"linha2\"")
```

Comment: Os campos com quebras de linha embutidos devem ser colocados dentro de aspas duplas.